# Input type image validation in add field in admin grid custom module

Tags: magento-1, grid, validation

How to make the add field for image in custom module admin grid as required entry?

The following is the way i have given , but it is not taking as required - entry field while saving.

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'background_image', 
            'image',
            array(
                'label' => $this->__("Background Image"),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => 'true',
                'name' => 'background_image',
                'note' => $this->__("Background Image")
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'background_image_hover', 
            'image',
            array(
                'label' => $this->__("Background Hover Image"),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => 'true',
                'name' => 'background_image_hover',
                'note' => $this->__("Background Hover Image")
            )
        );
```

Comment: Have you tried with 'required' => true,
without ' quotes ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem happens because the image field type uses `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image` which in the function `getElementHtml` calls `setClass` this un-setting any previously set classes for example the required-entry class :(

What is should do is call `$this->addClass('input-file');` so I guess this is a bug in Magento :(

Comment: Is there any other possiblity to add class required-entry

Comment: The only other thing is to specify your own form element mapping and so you do not have to update the core `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image` file. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30203/158

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code after addField :

```
$field1->setAfterElementHtml('<script>
//< ![C
$("image").addClassName("required-entry required-file ");
// here goes your custom Javascript

//]]>
</script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use type file instead image like below

```
$fieldSet->addField(
            'image', 'file', array(
                   'label'    => $this->__("Background Hover Image"),
                   'class'    => 'required-entry',
                   'required' => true,
                   'name'     => 'image',
                   )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change field type to '**imagefile**':

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'background_image', 
    'imagefile',
    array(
        'label' => $this->__("Background Image"),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => 'true',
        'name' => 'background_image',
        'note' => $this->__("Background Image")
    )
);
```